# CPU getting choked when below code is executed

Tags: performance

```
   public bool CheckIfValidSignedPdfExists(string fileServerPath, int memberagreementId)
        {
            var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(fileServerPath);

            if (filePaths.Length < 2)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var fileInfo = new List<FileInfo>();
            foreach (var path in filePaths)
            {
                if (File.Exists(path))
                    fileInfo.Add(new FileInfo(path));
            }
            if (fileInfo.Count < 2)
                return false;

            else
            {
                fileInfo = fileInfo.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTimeUtc).Take(2).ToList();
                //Rules: 1. Name 2.size 3. Last write time 4. Extension
                var firstPdf = fileInfo.FirstOrDefault();
                var lastPdf = fileInfo.LastOrDefault();

                var firstFileNameCheck = string.Concat(Convert.ToString(memberagreementId), ".pdf");
                var lastFileNameCheck = lastPdf.Name.StartsWith(Convert.ToString(memberagreementId) + "-")
                    && lastPdf.Name.EndsWith(".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

                if ((firstPdf.Name.Equals(firstFileNameCheck, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) &&
                    (lastFileNameCheck) && (firstPdf.Length > lastPdf.Length) && (firstPdf.LastWriteTimeUtc >= lastPdf.LastWriteTimeUtc))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

When this piece of code is running, we can see the cpu spike and the thread always relate to the above code.
[HIGH CPU Thread Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onZVQ.png)
[CPU Spike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTnMr.png)

We are not sure what wrong we are doing in this code which is causing this issue.

Comment: have you tried stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: Its happening on production.

Comment: I think this is likely dependent of the file system configuration. What kind of FS is used in production (NTFS, FAT, NFS, etc. with/without compression) and what kind of devices (SATA SSD, Nvme SSD, HDD). The NtQueryAttribute is used to stat the files so to get the file infos (FileInfo including timings). Note that some Windows plugins/services/applications can slow this down.